# how do I know if terraform aws_elasticsearch_domain "advanced_options" supports something like cluster_max_shards_per_node

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-opensearch

Basically I am reading the docs... https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain

And there is an advanced_options defined as "Key-value string pairs to specify advanced configuration options"

But how do I find out what advanced options are supported...  I am specifically trying to configure the max_shards_per_node, but looking to learn to fish here as well.

I did try a couple guesses...  and got a ValidationException.  So something knows what is allowed...

Also, I can't use phillbaker/eslasticsearch because the cluster is private, and so terraform can't hit the api's to do the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I find out what advanced options are supported...

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/opensearch/domain.go#L1338), you'll see that there are two advanced options:

- `rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index`
- `override_main_response_version`